# Vue-apollo 4 does not work properly fetch data with chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, graphql, vuejs3, vue-apollo

Following the steps described in the official documentation to use `vue-apollo 4` and the composition `API of vue 3`, everything works fine when I `Firefox` but it does not happen when I use `Chrome`, in `Chrome`, I get an error like this fetch error,
[image: chrome-network-tab]

both when making queries and mutations, but in `Firefox`, all the responses are obtained correctly as seen in the network tabs `Firefox` response network tab:
[image: firefow-network-tab]

and `Chrome` response network tab:
[image: chrome-response-network-tab]

Expected behaviour: Full response in `Chrome` as the result in `Firefox`
Resulting behaviour: Failed to get data on `Chrome` (empty network tab)

To try a little more, I have followed the example of Natalia Tepluhina described here https://dev.to/n_tepluhina/vue-apollo-v4-the-first-look-c32 and tested in both browsers, `Chrome/Chromium` and also `Firefox` and the result is the same in `Firefox` it works but not in `Chrome`

Try in older projects with older versions of `vue` and `vue-apollo` with the same result, error in `Chrome`

```
Chrome version:  86.0.4240.111 (x86_64)
Mozilla Firefox: version 82.0 (x86_64)
```

Comment: github issues are for this kind of problems

Comment: Thanks, here the github link for future reference https://github.com/vuejs/vue-apollo/issues/1096